# Регулярное выражение как обозначить пробел или наоборот его отсутствие

Tags: регулярные-выражения

1. High levls 1.179
2. High_levls 1.179
3. Highlevls 1.179

Как обозначить через регулярку что это одно и тоже выражение: наличие пробела/отсутствие пробела либо же нижнее подчеркивание

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В регулярных выражениях есть спецсимвол, который означает любой пробельный символ (включая таб).

```
\s
```

Аналогично, можно указать, чтобы это был любой непробельный символ

```
\S
```

Таким образов в вашем случае регулярное выражение будет следующим:

```
^High[\s_]?levls 1.179$
```

В квадратных скобках перечисляются возможные символы в данной возиции, а с помощью вопросительного знака указываем, что там может быть 1 из них или не быть вовсе.
Символы **^** и **$** означают начало и конец строки соответственно. То есть, если эта подстрока находится в другой строке, то их следует убрать.

```
High[\s_]?levls 1.179
```

Comment: Все Спасибо Вам Добрый Человек !!! )

Comment: Пожалуйста Вам!

Answer (score 2):

Например, так:

```js
const str = `
  High levls 1.179
  High_levls 1.179
  Highlevls 1.179
`;

const re = /High[ _]?levls/g;

console.log(str.match(re));
```

Или так:

```js
const str = `
  High levls 1.179
  High_levls 1.179
  Highlevls 1.179
`;

const re = /High(?: |_)?levls/g;

console.log(str.match(re));
```

Или даже так:

```js
const str = `
  High levls 1.179
  High_levls 1.179
  Highlevls 1.179
`;

const re = /High(?: |_|)levls/g;

console.log(str.match(re));
```

Comment: Thanks :)      ........